# Why does waitpid() only return 1 for all child processes?

Tags: c

I have a handler for `SIGCHLD` in a process that spawns off many children.

This code is inside my handler and `pid` is always `1`. I've read that `pid` should be the child process `id`. Why do I keep getting back `1`?

```
int status;
pid_t pid;

while(pid = waitpid(-1, &status, WNOHANG) > 0)
{        
    if  (WIFEXITED(status))
        printf("Child %ld: Ended properly and returned %d\n", pid, WEXITSTATUS(status));
    else
        printf("Child crashed\n");
}
```

Code to initialize the handler.

```
void initSIGCHLDSignalHandler()
{
    struct sigaction act;

    memset(&act,'\0',sizeof(struct sigaction));
    sigemptyset(&act.sa_mask);
    act.sa_flags = SA_NOCLDSTOP | SA_RESTART;
    act.sa_handler = SIGCHLD_SignalHandler;

    sigaction(SIGCHLD, &act, NULL);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine you want

```
while((pid = waitpid(-1, &status, WNOHANG)) > 0)
```

since right now all you're getting is "true".  (Your compiler probably warns about this, so be reading your compiler warnings.)

Comment: I just did that as you posted. Worked. Thank you.